# NewRelic ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I have a Rails app running on Heroku and I have NewRelic set to track its perfromance. Sometimes, it raises the following error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`. The cause of the error appears to be the format of the request (`*/*`). The action it is set to accept only `html` format requests:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

Any ideas how I can prevent getting this error?

Answer (score -1):

If you are only serving HTML, there is no need for the `respond_to` block. This may seem confusing, but it's part of Rails's "Convention Over Configuration" mantra. I'd have to see more of the controller to give you the precise line to use, but if you are following rails naming conventions, deleting that whole block should just work.

From the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) on the subject

> Note that we don't have explicit render at the end of the index action
>   in accordance with "convention over configuration" principle. The rule
>   is that if you do not explicitly render something at the end of a
>   controller action, Rails will automatically look for the
>   action_name.html.erb template in the controller's view path and render
>   it

Comment: Without respond_to it will give the following error, so that's not a solution.  ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template my_app/pages/index, my_app/application/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["*/*;"], ...

Comment: Will you edit your question and add your full controller/corresponding view directory? I'll update my solution when I see that. As I stated in my reply, without more information it's impossible to give the correct solution, but my guess is that you are not following Rails's naming conventions.

Comment: It is a static page. All that I do in controller action is to do this.

Comment: Understood. What is the name of the controller and what is in app/views ? Please update the question with this information :)